# Replace ckeditor content and add undo history entry

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a basic functionality I need to implement and can't find the information on how to do it: I simply want to replace all of CKEditor's content with custom markup and add an undo history entry so you can go back to the version before replacing.

1. So the basic command for replacing the content is `editor.setData` but it won't add an undo history, entry wrapping the call in `editor.model.change` won't change the behavior too.
2. Then there is somewhere deep in the documentationthe information on how to add (but not replace) custom html to the editor which is adding an undo history entry:

   ```
   this.editor.model.change((writer) => {
         const html = '<p>aaa</p><ul><li>huu</li><li>zzzz</li></ul><p>ssss</p>'
         const viewFragment = this.editor.data.processor.toView(html);
         const modelFragment = this.editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
         this.editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
         this.editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
         this.editor.editing.view.scrollToTheSelection();
   });
   ```

So how do I **replace** the content of the editor **and** add an undo history entry? I can only achieve one of the requirements but not both.

Comment: Is this related to your earlier question about dropdown, I guess? How are you managing the undo history?

Comment: Please could you provide live example so you receive more responses

Comment: @Azeem No this not related to my other question. It's just my last problem i need to solve.

Comment: @HusseinAkar The simple example is `editor.setData('<b>Hello World</b>')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that [selects all](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_select-all_selectallediting-SelectAllEditing.html) the text first and then [inserts](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-insertContent) custom text:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Undo from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/src/undo';
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';

class Replace extends Plugin {
    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;

        editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'Replace', locale => {
            const replaceButtonView = new ButtonView( locale );

            replaceButtonView.set( {
                label: 'Replace',
                withText: true,
            });

            replaceButtonView.on( 'execute', () => {
                editor.execute('selectAll');
                const html = '<p>aaa</p><ul><li>huu</li><li>zzzz</li></ul><p>ssss</p>';
                const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView(html);
                const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
                editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment);
                editor.editing.view.scrollToTheSelection();
            });

            return replaceButtonView;
        } );
    }
}

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [ Essentials, Paragraph, Undo, Replace ],
        toolbar: [ 'undo', 'Replace' ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        console.log( 'Editor was initialized', editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } );
```

Live:

[image: CKEditor5-Replace-Undo-Demo]

Comment: Perfect! The "selectAll" trick is documented nowhere but is exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In Azeem's answer the `selectAll` step seems to create it's own history entry so undoing takes an extra click and you also see the document get selected when undoing.

Here is my solution which is identical except it explicitly passes a selection to `insertContent` instead of relying on the default behavior of using the current selection when none is provided.

```
const range = editor.model.createRangeIn(editor.model.document.getRoot());
const viewFragment = editor.data.processor.toView(text);
const modelFragment = editor.data.toModel(viewFragment);
editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment, range);
editor.editing.view.scrollToTheSelection();
```